# How to enable Menu and Tools tab in Excel menubar

Tags: excel, menu

I am using excel 2007. I cannot see Menu and Tools on my menubar. I wanted to activate Analysis ToolPak. I clicked on Excel icon (top left) and then options and then add-in and activate Analysis ToolPak. However I cannot see this anywhere in the menubar along with Menu and Tools. I searched a lot on internet but could not find any solution. So, I have three issues (all are same)

-how do I enable Menu and Tools option
-how do I access Analysis ToolPak and use it (although I activated it from option but I cannot find it anywhere on the ribbon)

Any idea?

Comment: Click the file icon and hit Excel Option at the bottom of the menu. It is at the left side of Exit Excel button. https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/What-happened-to-the-Options-command-on-the-Tools-menu--68e30b29-b5c9-4565-8e52-307ac28bff2a?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA

Answer (score 1):

When Enabled it will not appear as a separate tab it will appear on the end of the Data tab, in a section called Analysis. You should also have different options under the What-If Analysis in the Data tab.

I might be wrong but the Menu and Tools were removed and replaced by the ribbon, you can download an addon to put them back in however specific tools are now in different locations in the Ribbon.

This might help finding the locations you require: http://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleId=7603

Comment: Yup...got it. Thanx Peter.